# Trying to concat a string in php but it thinks its an array

Tags: php, string

Weird situation and I'm not even sure what to call it (hence unable to find any previous posts).

I'm passing in a variable that is a string as function, and then attempting to concat it to another string as such:

```
function saveFunction($number){

$myStr = "drawer-$number[]";
return $myStr;

}
```

So the output should be :

```
saveFunction("2")
"drawer-2[]"
```

However, because it thinks I am accessing $number as an array because of the brackets, the output is:

```
"0"
```

I even tried this:

```
function saveFunction($number){

$myStr = "drawer-$number";
return $myStr + "[]";

}
```

And got the same result.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does forming the string like `$myStr = "drawer-".$number."[]";` help?

Comment: Eliminate the ambiguity: `$myStr = "drawer-{$number}[]";`

Comment: And `return $myStr + "[]";`?!? `+` is the __addition__ operator in PHP; `.` is the concatenation operator

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes in PHP are tricky. They *interpret* the string. This is why `"drawing-$number"` works in the first place.

Sometimes your string doesn't lend itself for automatic interpretation. You can use the always safe concatenation:

```
return "drawer-" . $number . "[]";
```

Or use `{}` to help the automatic detection:

```
return "drawer-{$number}[]"; // as opposed to: "drawer-{$number[]}"
```

Or use `sprintf`:

```
return sprintf("drawer-%s[]", $number); // %s because $number is actually a string, not an int
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just concat the variable with the string like this:

```
<?php

    function saveFunction($number){
        return $myStr = "drawer-" . $number . "[]";
    }


    echo saveFunction("2");

?>
```

Output:

```
drawer-2[]
```

For further information see also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php